# Adding mousedown function in <tr> with javascript table creation not working

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am creating a html table using javascript as follows:

```
var table = document.getElementById("ordertable");  
            var rowcount = document.getElementById("ordertable").rows.length;       
            var row = table.insertRow(rowcount);        
            row.id="row_"+rowcount; 
            row.className = "rec_unselected";
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(4)
```

I want to add a `onmousedown` function in  in insertion step so I added like follows:

```
row.innerHTML = "onmousedown='RowClick(this,false);'";
```

But it is not working!

I am expecting the table like:

```
`<tr onmousedown="RowClick(this,false);" id="row_1" class="rec_unselected"`>
            <td>any value</td>
            <td>any value</td>
            <td>any value</td>.....................
```

But I am getting as `<tr  id="row_1" class="rec_unselected">`

Comment: Just add the event listener in JavaScript, you are adding it as essentially text inside the HTML element and not as a attribute like you think.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek can you post as an answer? it will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add your event listener with JavaScript by doing:

```
row.onmousedown = function(){ RowClick(this,false); }
```

What `row.innerHTML = "onmousedown='RowClick(this,false);'"` does is add that text into the element itself (and not as a `onmousedown` attribute event).

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to change is not the `innerHTML`. But since you are doing this in JS already, you should not move the function call to your HTML, but have it all in your scripts.

You add the click event to your row in JS like this:

```
row.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
   RowClick(event.target, false);
});
```